# Inserting object in local Storage, how to stop same data to be inserted in local storage in Angular 6

Tags: angular

```
  select(product){ 
    if(product){
      this.check = true
      this.orderService.create(product);
      console.log("selected product",product.selected);
      this.router.navigate(['shopping-cart']);

    }
    else{
      this.check = false
      alert("product is already added");
      console.log("selected product",product);

    }
```

this is my product.component.ts file

```
create(product){


      if (localStorage.getItem('cart') === null){
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this.order));
      }
      else{
        this.order = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        this.order.push(product);
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this.order));
      }
      console.log('order has been push' , this.order);
    }


  getCart() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
  }

  removeItem(item){
    this.order = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    this.order.splice(item,1);
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this.order));
    console.log('item: ' , item);
  }

  }
```

this is `order.service.ts` file where I set my local storage

Every time when I add product its been inserted in `localstorage` in this.order array, but the same data is been inserted and displaying. How can I avoid it?

Comment: How your `product` object looks like, can you post it or update in question?

Comment: product ={id: 1, name: "bread", createdAt: "2018-07-16T19:08:38.000Z", updatedAt: "2018-07-16T19:08:38.000Z"}

Comment: Before pushing new product to `this.order` array, check for the product existence using the `product.id`. I will post the answer that will tell you how to do

Comment: yes  i want to check like this, but dont know how to check,please give solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before pushing the product to array, check for the product existence like below

```
create(product){
    this.order = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    var index = this.order.findIndex(item => item.id == product.id);
    if (index !== -1) {
       this.order.splice(index, 1);
    }
    this.order.push(product);
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this.order));
}
```